# Angular 2 Datatime picker in angular-cli

Tags: angular, datetimepicker, angular-cli

I'm looking for datetime picker, which I could use to add into one input field date and time in yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss format. I used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetime-picker but after recreating project on base with angular-cli I'm stuck with ERROR in Ng2DatetimePickerModule is not an NgModule.
(this datetime picker wasn't updated since half of year).
I would be very grateful for alternative.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest creating your own component using jQuery UI or HTML5

Answer (score 0):

Found solution for error.
In app.modules had to set,

import { Ng2DatetimePickerModule } from 'ng2-datetime-picker/src';

instead of documented
import { Ng2DatetimePickerModule } from 'ng2-datetime-picker';

Answer (score 0):

You can use '@neoprospecta/angular-datetimepicker' that is a fork of this same package but with some differences like does not change the iput type as the ng2-datetime-picker does.